# LINQ returning IEnumerable<string> value in seeming charArray

Tags: c#, linq

I have a an

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
```

within this IEnumerable I have a Key called "JobDetails"  In order to ensure this key is there I am using the following statement;

```
  var avalue = from val in tokensReturned where val.Key == "JobDetails" select val.Key;
```

which I would expect to pass this Assert as the Key is there

```
Assert.AreEqual("JobDetails", avalue);
```

The message I am getting is Expected: 'J' But was "JobDetails"

Is also states that the values differ at index 0

if I add .First() to avalue in the assert then the test passes, is this the correct thing to do? I am a bit of a LINQ newbie and don't want to add .First because it works, I want to know what the right thing to do is.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to add a `.First()`... The `select` will return another `IEnumerable<>` with as many elements as there are elements in `tokensReturned` with `Key == "JobDetails"`. An `IEnumerable<T>` with 0 or 1 elements is still an `IEnumerable<T>`. It doesn't implicitly/automatically "decade" to its "generic" `T` type (`string` in your case). By using `.First()` you extract the first element of the `IEnumerable<T>`, that is a `T` object. If there are no elements, you'll get an exception.

If you are sure there should be a single element, I often suggest using `.Single()`, that will check that there are exactly 1 element (this is an additional check, useful when you work with DB, where what you think should return 1 element doesn't always return 1 element, because what you think is contained in the DB isn't exactly what is contained in the DB)

Comment: Great thanks, it's just so easy to go, that works it must be right, I had sort of assumed/worked out what you have just said, but it is nice to have that backed up.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already filtering out only those items that match, you only need to check how many you have:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, avalue.Count());
```

If you try to extract the first item with `First()` or `Single()`, you run the risk of your test throwing a non-assert exception because you don't *have* a first (or single) item.

Comment: Thank you, whilst the other answer answers my initial question, this is definitely a better way for my test. cheers